# Django - Using get_readonly_fields but getting 'NoneType' object is not iterable' when adding new record

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

here's the thing, if the X field (non required) has a value then none of the others fields can be edited (when editing). However, if this values is empty then all the other fields should go back to normal. I did that using this inside the app's admin.py

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    
    if obj:
        lb = obj.X
        if lb:
            return ['v','p','e']
        else:
            return []
```

This works when you enter existing objects, however when adding a new instance I get the yellow page with the 'NoneType' object is not iterable' error. I'm aware this because the OBJ is null, when looking up for similar problems I found this is a django bug with get read only fields, apparently. Searched for solutions but they make that the created object can't be edited anymore (at least the ones I found).

Is there a workaround or another method I can use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the **`get_readonly_fields(...)`** metho returning **`None`** if there is no **`obj`**. So, Change your method as,

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj and obj.X:
        return ['v', 'p', 'e']
    return super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
```

Comment: It worked, looks like the return at the end was what I was missing, thanks!